# SARIMAX with seasonality greater than one year

Tags: python, time-series

I would use *Statsmodels SARIMAX* with data having seasonality greater than one year.
In my case, I have seasonality equal *4* years, therefore I have tried:

```
smt.SARIMAX(endog, order=(p, d, q), seasonal_order=(P,D,Q,4))
```

Is it correct set `seasonality = 4` when the seasonality is equal 4 years?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.statespace.sarimax.SARIMAX.html) of statsmodels:

> `s` is an integer giving the periodicity (number of periods in season), often it is 4 for quarterly data or 12 for monthly data. Default is no seasonal effect.

So it depends on how you have your data recorded, if each entry is a year, your seasonality would be 4, however if you have monthly data, then it would be 36.